# Knowing whether a pronominal verb is reflexive or reciprocal

Tags: grammaire, verbes-pronominaux, pronoms-réfléchis, pronoms-reciproques

When I look at the two sentences below how can I tell straight away whether they are a reflexive action or a reciprocal action as they both have 'se' in the sentence:

> Elles se maquillent
>
> Elles se parlent

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to look at the meanings of the verbs.

**Elles se maquillent** : reflexive because we assume each girl is making herself up.
**Elles se parlent** : reciprocal because we assume there are two or more of them and they're talking to each other/one another.

Obviously context is important, but to change from reciprocal to reflexive (or *vice versa*) we'd usually have something to give that context.
 *Elles se maquillent **l'une l'autre**.* -> reciprocal (could be complicated simultaneously but we can imagine they do it in turns)
*Elles se parlent toujours **toutes seules** !*  « Toutes seules » makes the difference : each one is talking to herself -> reflexive.